# At least the first 31 or 63 characters of an internal name are significant?

Tags: c++, c, variables, names, kr-c

Here's a direct quote from the Book (K&R, 2nd ed, p. 35):

> "At least the first 31 characters of an internal name are significant.
>   For function names and external variables, the number may be less than
>   31, because external names may be used by assemblers and loaders over
>   which the language has no control. For external names, the standard
>   guarantees only for 6 characters and a single case."

And in C99 there is no length limitation on its internal names, but only the first 63 are guaranteed to be significant (§5.2.4.1 Translation Limits).

My question is why are these limits specifically **31** or **63**? Why this number specifically? Why not **19, 24** or any other number? If it's an implementation issue, is there a benefit from making it **31** or **63**?

Comment: Probably if you say the book title we can try to understand.

Comment: Well the tag is kr-c, so I took a wild stab in the dark and looked in K&R, and surprise surprise there it was. (Page 35, 2nd edition.)

Comment: Computers feed on powers of two. There, I said it.

Comment: "but only the first 63 are significant." AFAIK, it is again a minimum.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand this is not 31 bits it's 31 characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler/linker writers associated with a language design committee usually impose some limits so that they can make assumptions in the implementation of the toolchain or in the accompanying binary file formats (e.g., [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF), etc).  The numbers 31 and 63 were probably chosen simply because they are 2<sup>n</sup>-1 and programmers like 2<sup>n</sup> for some silly reason.  The -1 is usually to account for either a leading `_` or a trailing `NUL` character in the name.

Comment: what is meant by toolchain,and about 2n-1 can give an example i'm confused

Comment: Since it's C, a trailing \0 is a safe bet. @HATEMEL-AZAB: "Toolchain" usually refers to the sequence of tools used to build a C program: preprocessor, compiler, linker.

Comment: Usually naming conventions at the compiler <-> linker level are based on mangling so I would suspect the leading underscore assumption myself.  The names included in the binary symbol tables are not usually NULL-terminated.  They are padded to a fixed length.  In any case, it's just a convenient limit.