# c99: 63 characters of an internal name are significant?

Tags: c++, c, variables, names, kr-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At least the first 31 ,or 63 characters of an internal name are significant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141422/at-least-the-first-31-or-63-characters-of-an-internal-name-are-significant)

Here's a direct quote from the Book (K&R, 2nd ed, p. 35):

> "At least the first 31 characters of an internal name are significant.
>   For function names and external variables, the number may be less than
>   31, because external names may be used by assemblers and loaders over
>   which the language has no control. For external names, the standard
>   guarantees only for 6 characters and a single case."

and in **c99 there is no length limitation on its internal names, but only the first 63 are significant.**

My question is why are these limits specifically **31** or **63**? Why this number specifically why not **19,24** or any other number? If it's an implementation issue, is there a benefit from making it **31** or **63**?

Comment: Blind guess, but perhaps because both 31 and 63, after adding a '\0' at the end, give a power of 2.

Comment: i think it may be duplicated if no constructive answer and that's why it was closed there.

Comment: @HATEMEL-AZAB, it was VERY constructive, both the old answer and Matthew. If you don't understand it, you need to study more.

Comment: it is but i'am answering the one who said Reposting the same question that was closed later is not how we do things here.

Comment: because i'm the one who asked the question the old and this one,but they closed it there as they see it's not constructive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's so the length can be a power of two, even including NUL-termination.

Comment: and what is the advantages from make being power of two

Comment: @HATEMEL-AZAB, it tends to be more efficient.  For instance, often, the actual chunks malloc returns are in units of a power of two.

Comment: @Matthew: That's a myth. There's no benefit to allocators which return power-of-two-sized chunks only, and tons of disadvantages. Anybody still doing that is living in the 70s, and unlike some implementation practices where "living in the 70s" has at least some value, this particular one has no value.

Comment: Ehm, at least recently @R.. uCLibc allocator was living in the 70s.  If you are surrounded by crazy, sometimes it's best to act crazy yourself... :-)

Comment: @R.., I didn't mean an allocator that returned only power-of-two-size chunks.  Rather, one that returned multiples of a power of 2.  E.g. if the unit is 16, it could return 16 bytes, or a multiple thereof (32, 160, etc.).  Either way, I am not saying all allocators are like that.  For instance, AIX 3.1 had a power-of-two-sized chunk only [policy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/sys_mem_alloc.htm), and it was released after C89, and well after the 70's (1990).

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: uClibc's default allocator is dlmalloc, which, essentially, is the only reasonable/viable malloc algorithm. (Various tweaks/variants are possible, but its basic idea of sorting free chunks by lists of chunks of the same size is the only known reasonable algorithm.) It has two other options, one of which might suck that bad; I'm not sure.

Comment: @Matthew: Then the issue is not being a power of two, but being a multiple of the alignment (so typically a multiple of 8, 16, or 32, depending on the machine).

Comment: the answer means that every thing should be taken as power of 2 ,but for some language the first 6 characters are significant is this is power of 2?

Comment: @R.., right, that's basically what my first comment meant, though I don't know if all such malloc implementations use the alignment as the unit.  However, AIX 3.1 in fact did what you said (always an exact power of 2, not just a multiple of one).

Comment: @HATEMEL-AZAB, I never said every limit is a power of 2.  6 obviously isn't.

Comment: @R.., at least the one I was subjected to was power of 2.  I think we fixed that once we switched from vendor ported version of old Snapgear tree. :-)

Comment: I believe these are what one calls "buddy system allocators". Despite the (fading, but still present) hype about their instructional value for simplicity, they're no simpler than the basic dlmalloc algorithm, much slower (O(log n) for free instead of O(1)), and fragment memory much worse. This is a case where putting the extra constraint (power of 2 "buddies") that was intended to be something you could take advantage of really creates *more work* for you rather than less.